# SQLAlcehmy - Can't determine which FROM clause to join

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have  3 models and I need some columns from both of them:

```
class candidates(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable= False)
    surname = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable= False)
    father_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable= False)
        
class students(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    candidate_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('candidates.id'), nullable= False) # Foreign key to Candidates   
    type = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable= False) 
    family_status = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable= False)
    education_status = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable= False)

class graduate_students(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('students.id'), nullable= False) 
    work_place = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable= False)
    salary = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable= False)


result = graduate_students.query.with_entities(
    graduate_students.id, students.id, 
    candidates.id, candidates.name, candidates.surname).join(students).join(candidates).all()


print(result)
```

But Interpreter gives me this error:

"Can't determine which FROM clause to join "
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't determine which FROM clause to join from, there are multiple FROMS which can join to this entity. Please use the .select_from() method to establish an explicit left side, as well as providing an explcit ON clause if not present already to help resolve the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if request.method == "POST":
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_question = form.save()  
            student = Student.objects.get(user = request.user)
            new_question.student = student
            new_question.save()
            if((len(request.FILES) =
```